# Почему не хватает оперативной памяти?

Tags: железо

после переустановления Windows возникла такая проблема. Часто пишет что не хватает RAM
У самого 8gb DDR4 и раньше подобных проблем не встречал
Удивительно то что через диспетчер задач сами процессы такие как хром, фигма, visual studio code употребляют не много. Но куда то еще идет оперативная память. Даже если выключить все программы 3-4gb загруженно
Скачал RamMAp
И по их данным 1.4гб идет на Process Private
И 2.6 на Mapped files, как по мне дело в этих 2.6. Кто может подсказать в чем дело

Comment: Widnows их использует, но не пишет об этом. Попробуй поставить SSD или выделить swap для оперативки, если это возможно на Windows. У меня на двух разных ноутбуках при одинаковой оперативной памяти и загруженности разница в частоте нехватке памяти очень сильная. На Linux сильное влияние оказало наличие swap-раздела, по размеру сопоставимого с оперативной памятью

Comment: @MikhailIonkin а причём линукс ? RamMap типично виндовая прога

Comment: @MaximLensky так проблемы с железом могут быть общими.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin по моему так ...в линукс swap обязателен а в windows чем больше ОЗУ тем меньше файл подкачки ..разве нет ? к примеру на 16Ггб Озу файл подкачки отсутствует

Comment: @MaximLensky не думаю, что в Windows есть обратная зависимость между ОЗУ и подкачкой. Но увеличить этот файл не помешает, если есть проблемы с ОЗУ. Как понимаю, mapped files -- это [Memory-mapped_file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), или ["Отображение файла в память"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C). Т.е. проблема, на мой взгляд, в том, что либо не хватает swap, либо обмен с этим swap медленный. Для 2й причины поможет SSD

Comment: @MaximLensky не знаю насчет обязательности в Linux, но тут играет роль в первую очередь не наличие, а размер swap. Ибо можно сделать его в несколько мегабайт -- тогда его все равно, что не будет

Comment: @MikhailIonkin вот тут я согласен НО в Линукс Swap обязателен а вот в Windows файл подкачки не обязателен при 16Ггб но при 8 Ггб по моему 2048 должно быть вроде бы ...это если 10ка

Comment: procexp.exe точнее покажет, кто жрёт память. https://live.sysinternals.com/

Comment: у меня в линуксе свопа нет и никогда не было! кто вам сказал такую глупость что он обязателен? и да, причём тут линукс? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потребовалось увеличить файл подкачки до 2048